# Magento2: Not in value Category ids product collection issue

Tags: magento2, category-products

Product collection issue

```
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

products  = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addCategoriesFilter('category_id', array(
                array('nin' => $currentCategoryId),
            ))
            ->setOrder('price', 'ASC')
            ->load();
```

Comment: What issue you are facing here?

Comment: @aman going to php session close function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fetch product collection by categories you can try this code:

```
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');

 $categories = [2,3,5];//category ids array

 $collection = $productCollection ->create();
 $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
 $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['nin' => $categories]);
 $collection->setPageSize(10)
 print_r($collection->getData());
```

Comment: I have tried this code got the error message Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 400592896 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Try the updated answer, as I limit the item to 10, seems it is printing lots of data so it went out of memory

Answer (score 1):

### First, you to have to check why the parameter is not working

If you check **addCategoriesFilter**  function definition, then you will find it *support a parameter which is an array*. the parameter is **a one-dimensional** array which supports **index as condition Type and value as filter value**.Like

```
$categoriesFilter  =  
 [
    'in' => [10,15],
    'nin' => [12,18]
 ]
```

**So,you have to change**

> ```
> addCategoriesFilter('category_id', array(
>                 array('nin' => $currentCategoryId),
>             ))
> ```

to

> addCategoriesFilter(array('nin' => $currentCategoryId))

```
 public function addCategoriesFilter(array $categoriesFilter)
    {
        foreach ($categoriesFilter as $conditionType => $values) {
            $categorySelect = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
                ['cat' => $this->getTable('catalog_category_product')],
                'cat.product_id'
            )->where($this->getConnection()->prepareSqlCondition('cat.category_id', ['in' => $values]));
            $selectCondition = [
                $this->mapConditionType($conditionType) => $categorySelect
            ];
            $this->getSelect()->where($this->getConnection()->prepareSqlCondition('e.entity_id', $selectCondition));
        }
        return $this;
    }
```